# Is there an elegant way to access the camera from the inappbrowser under iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, inappbrowser

I am currently developing an hybrid app with Cordova. The project is mainly a webview for an external website (implemented with the Cordova inappbrowser plugin). On this site I want the user to be able to take a picture with their device camera and use it on the website. On Android I intercept the "loadstart" event and launch the camera plugin for a specific url, which works just as I want it to. On iOS however, the camera does not launch and I get a warning 
`Warning: Attempt to present <CDVCameraPicker: 0xXXXXXXXXX> on <MainViewController: 0xXXX> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` 
in XCode.
After some research I found out, that this is expected behaviour for the inappbrowser. Closing the inappbrowser to launch the camera and open the inappbrowser again is no option for me.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to show the camera on top of the inappbrowser?
My workaroud so far is to use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`, which works (kind of). It opens a dialog where the user can choose between "take picture" and "choose file", if he chooses "take picture" the camera opens and I can get the picture to the website.

**Question 2:** Can I bypass this choose dialog and go directly to the camera when the button is clicked?
I know that both modifications have to take place in native iOS code (which I have never used).
Any help will be appreciated and **THANK YOU** for your time.
Related question:

- [Cordova IOS camera plugin not working when trying to open from inappbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218829/cordova-ios-camera-plugin-not-working-when-trying-to-open-from-inappbrowser)

**Update:**
The call which seems to break the camera is:

```
__weak CDVCamera* weakSelf = self;

...

[weakSelf.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    weakSelf.hasPendingOperation = NO;
}];
```

**Question:** How can I present the camera on top of the inappbrowser plugin?
I tried to get the rootViewController but it did not work:

- `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]`

Comment: I never got this approach to work, but managed to achieve what i wanted. See my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165608/i-need-help-modifying-the-inappbrowser-in-native-code/39226377#39226377).